# How do I pick out strings with certain extension from a tuple list in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to pick out all .txt files within a tuple list, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

This is what the list resembles:

```
list = ('something.docx', 'something.txt')
```

How would I instruct the computer to look through the list and pick out 'something.txt' and print it(for example)?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *"..within a tuple list"*. Both are different, what you're having is a tuple.

Comment: `list` is not valid as variable name...

Comment: @ansi_lumen Yes it is. It's just not advisable.

Comment: Your question already has good answers below. For more complicated problems you should study regular expressions too.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, it is not. If you lint your code, you would know.

Comment: @ansi_lumen Yes, it is. If you run your code, you would know.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Bad practice is not to be advertised to newbies by responsible folks. Sad.

Comment: @ansi_lumen I did not advertise bad practice. I explicitly wrote that it is not advisable. Claiming that names of builtins are not valid names seriously misrepresents how Python works, though. It can be misleading and hinder learning and understanding, as well as prevent awareness of the need to know names of buitins to avoid shadowing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
L = ('something.docx', 'something.txt', 'foobar.txt')
L2 = [x for x in L if x[-4:]==".txt"]
for i in L2:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
something.txt
foobar.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to filter only the text that ends with `.txt`:

```
[i for i in my_list if i.endswith('.txt')]
```

Given that you are working with a list (tuple in your case) of strings, you can use [endswith](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/endswith) method on each element to perform the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `os` module for that, for example, in a list comprehension like this:

```py
import os


files = ('something.docx', 'something.txt')
extension = '.txt'

all_txt = [
    file for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == extension
]

print(all_txt)

>>> ['something.txt']
```

Note: don't use `list` as a variable name since it is a `python reserved keyword`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to iterate and extract the matches with an if statement

```
    target_strings = [l for l in list if l=='something.txt'] # extract elemnts
    print(*target_string) # prints all elements
```

I don't know if your are looking for that, but you can use any condition

```
    target_strings = (l for l in list if your_condition) # extract elemnts
    print(*target_string) # prints all elements
```

Answer (score 0):

List-comprehension is probably the best way here, but for the sake of completeness, here is a solution using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```py
paths = ('something.docx', 'something.txt')

for path in filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".txt"), paths):
    print(path)
```

Gives:

```
something.txt
```

---

The main difference is that [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterator so if you only need to print (or just don't need to store all matches), this doesn't create another list in memory.